# Chronologically order two-digit years in cross table

Tags: r

I have a cross table (made with `table`) with individuals in the rows and years in the columns. To save horizontal space I'd like to use two-digit years rather than four-digit years (downstream this goes to LaTeX through `xtable`). But when I use an ordered factor (through either `ordered()` or `factor(..., ordered=TRUE)`) I get numerical ordering rather than chronological ordering.

How can I chronologically order the columns? It seems like when I pass the ordered factor into `table` I lose the ordering attribute.

```
# representative data
dates <- as.Date("2010-01-01") - seq(30*365)
DF <- data.frame(day=sample(dates, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 id=sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace=TRUE))
DF$year <- as.numeric(format(DF$day, "%Y"))

# the table I want
table(DF$id, DF$year)

# but I'd like two year dates to save horizontal space
# but keep chronological order
DF <- DF[order(DF$day), ]
DF$yearShort <- factor(format(DF$day, "%y"), ordered=TRUE)

# but even though yearShort is ordered, the table isn't
is.ordered(DF$yearShort)
tab <- table(DF$id, DF$yearShort)
tab

# I can't order by rownames, either
tab[, order(dimnames(tab)[[2]])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very proud of the solution but it does what you want it to do :)

```
> tab2 <- table(DF$id, DF$year)
> colnames(tab2) <- substr(colnames(tab2),3,4)
> tab2

    80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 98 99 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
  a  0  2  0  2  2  2  0  1  0  2  0  1  0  2  2  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
  b  1  1  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  2  1  0  0  0  2  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  3  0  1  0  0  0  1
  c  3  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  2  0
  d  0  0  1  3  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  3  1  1  0  1  0  0  2  0  1  0  1  2  0  0  0  0  0
  e  1  0  2  0  3  1  0  0  1  0  0  3  1  0  0  0  0  2  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: Sharp. This may be the only solution.